# TFS 2015.2 - (Jenkins) Linked artifact sources do not support triggers

Tags: jenkins, tfs

After successfully linking a Jenkins build artifact source to Release Management vNext in TFS 2015 Update 2 RTM (adding a Jenkins endpoint, linking to the source through Artifacts tab, finding build artifacts through TFS that were published in Jenkins and verifying by selecting the Jenkins artifacts in the Copy release task), it looks like in the Triggers tab, when trying to select Continuous Deployment, a warning symbol appears and the message says:

```
Linked artifact sources do not support triggers.
```

Any idea if it is possible to link a Jenkins build artifact source to trigger releases in TFS 2015.2 in Continuous Deployment? Looks like it only works for TFS builds. I see [this link that says "other sources" for builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/author-release-definition/more-release-definition#triggers) by using the REST API for RM but when clicking on the link, the section says in the body, "Content not available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario if choose Jenkins type in Artifacts. But if choose Build type, this warning won't show up.

Continuous Deployment doesn't support Jenkins Artifacts, you can submit a UserVoice at website: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot, Cece, that's exactly what I was seeing as well. I submitted a UserVoice request and I suppose I'll just have to wait until the REST API for RM comes out. Maybe I'll try creating an empty build definition that is triggered by the TFS REST API that has a CD trigger to RM as a temporary workaround.